# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float java.lang.Float.floatValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, svg, svg-android

When I launch my app this problem shows. This is my Java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), raw.canel);`


    imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
   setContentView(imageView);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could paste the stack trace of this exception. In which line does the error occurs?

Comment: The exception message is pretty self-explanatory. However I don't see you calling the method `floatValue` in your code, show us where you call it.

Comment: Also, what is your question?

Comment: the line cause the problem is

Comment: the line cause the problem is
the line cause the problem is
 SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), raw.canel);`

Comment: my quest is what sould i do for making my app launch

Comment: Could it be that `raw.canel` is a null `Float` reference and `SVGParser.getSVGFromResource()` expects a primitive `float`? I’m guessing a bit here. I don’t think we have enough information to do better.

Comment: (or maybe expects some other primitive type, perhaps `double`)

Comment: okey , thanks bur raw.canel is not null its SVG file then i see tutorial like this and it work normaly ,so i dont understand what i should do ,thanks for helping

Comment: This particular `NullPointerException` may (or may not) come from auto-unboxing a `Float` object. Hence my previous comments.

Comment: I suspect it is not the line you list itself that is failing, but something deeper inside the SVG parser.  It may be something in your SVG file that your library is not handling properly. It looks like you are using the svg-android library. Have you tried an alternative library, such as AndroidSVG?

Comment: You may want to edit your question to include a full stacktrace and it would probably be easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

This is the line where the exception is thrown:

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), raw.canel);
```

There are two possibilities: either `SVGParser` is `null` and therefore has no `getSVGFromResource`, or `raw` is `null` and has no `canel` member.

If your error is that `SVGParser` is `null`, then the problem is that you did not `import` `SVGParser`. In this case the solution is to import the package which contains `SVGParser`, since it is a `class` and it was not `import`ed, therefore the compiler thinks it is a variable and has not been initialized.

If your error is that `raw` is `null`, then the solution is to initialize it. In this case you have missed the part where the variable is being initialized. It is quite possible that you initialize it correctly, but after `onCreate` is being called, therefore the member is not initialized yet when you try to use it.

We need more information about the problem to give you a more specific solution.